# How do you remove a created element with an element that was created

Tags: javascript, html

Button that makes the box appear:

```
<button onclick="create()">create box</button>
<div id="trades"></div>
```

Where the box appears:

```
<div class="box" id="duplicater"> 
</div>
```

Function to create the box:

```
function create() {

   var box = document.createElement("div");
   box.setAttribute('class', 'itembox')

   //delete button to remove the box
   var remove = document.createElement("span");
   remove.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
   remove.setAttribute('id', 'Remove')
   remove.innerText = "x";
   box.appendChild(remove);

   var holder = document.createElement("p");
   holder.setAttribute('class', 'output');

   holder.innerText = "The text in the box"
   box.appendChild(holder);

   var trades = document.getElementById("trades");
   trades.appendChild(box);
}
```

Delete the box when the remove button is pressed:

```
var removeItem = document.getElementById("Remove")[0];
   removeItem.onclick = function() {
   trades.removeChild(box)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be achieved by calling the `remove()` method on the box element to be removed. Adding this code:

```
remove.onclick = function() {
    box.remove();
}
```

at the point in your `create()` function where you defined the `remove` element like so:

```js
function create() {

  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.setAttribute('class', 'itembox')

  //delete button to remove the box
  var remove = document.createElement("span");
  remove.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
  remove.setAttribute('id', 'Remove')
  remove.innerText = "x";
  box.appendChild(remove);

  // define onclick behavior for remove element
  // and call 'remove()' on the box element to
  // delete it as required
  remove.onclick = function() {
    box.remove();
  }

  var holder = document.createElement("p");
  holder.setAttribute('class', 'output');

  holder.innerText = "The text in the box"
  box.appendChild(holder);

  var trades = document.getElementById("trades");
  trades.appendChild(box);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create()">create box</button>
<div id="trades"></div>
```

As an additional note, the preferred method of event binding to the DOM is via `addEventListener()` rather than assigning handler functions to events like `onclick`. To make use of `addEventListener()` in your code, you could rewrite:

```
remove.onclick = function() {
    box.remove();
}
```

As:

```
remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box.remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

> The ChildNode.remove() method removes the object from the tree it belongs to.
>
> <sup>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove</sup>

At the same time, the main problem that I see with your code thus far is that it lacks encapsulation. Encapsulation is a word that has a lot of specific meanings attributed to it but it generally means that instances should be protected from other instances so that you always know which instance you're working on and you don't have to "find" it.

The easiest way to do this when working on DOM projects like this is to use [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

> One of the key features of the Web Components standard is the ability to create custom elements that encapsulate your functionality on an HTML page, rather than having to make do with a long, nested batch of elements that together provide a custom page feature.
>
> <sup>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements</sup>

Below I've created a class that extends `HTMLElement` such as to implement an autonomous custom element. I've then [separated the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and implemented the click event handler for the `.remove` button.

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that `id` attributes must be unique within the document. This means that you should not be assigning an id attribute with the value `remove` to every `remove` button.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.
>
> <sup>- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sup>

```js
class ItemBox extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // This must be done after the element is created because
        //   the element must not contain children upon creation
        setTimeout(_ => this.appendChildren(this.createChildren()))
    }
    createChildren() {
        return [
          this.createRemoveButton(),
          this.createOutputContainer()
        ]
    }
    appendChildren(children) {
        for(let child of children) {
            this.appendChild(child)
        }
    }
    createRemoveButton() {
        const element = document.createElement('span')
        element.classList.add('remove')
        element.innerText = `\u2715`
        element.addEventListener('click', event => this.remove())
        return element
    }
    createOutputContainer() {
        const element = document.createElement('p')
        element.classList.add('output')
        element.innerText = 'The text in the box'
        return element
    }
}
customElements.define('item-box', ItemBox)

const boxContainer = document.getElementById('box_container')
const createButton = document.getElementById('box_creator')
createButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    boxContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('item-box'))
})
```

```css
item-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    background: #DDD;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 5px;
}
item-box .remove,
item-box .output {
    padding: 5px;
}
item-box .remove {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}
item-box .output {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="box_creator">create box</button>
<div id="box_container"></div>
```